# Validating Solr queries against a schema

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr

I would like to validate queries against a schema before actually executing them.

Is there an official API which will give me access to a schema, or will I have to parse the Solr configuration XML myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual trick for finding these resources it to open the Admin interface with the developer network tool running in your browser, then navigating to the resource you're looking for while watching which requests your browser perform. Since the frontend is purely Javascript based and runs in your browser, it accesses everything through the API exposed by Solr.

You'll have to parse *something*, either in JSON or XML (probably) format. For my older, 4.10.2-installation, it is available as:

```
/solr/corename/admin/file?file=schema.xml&contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of what I thought would be the case.